# I'm trying to catch brute force against /xmlrpc.php with fail2ban

Tags: nginx, wordpress, fail2ban

I'm getting a ton of failed a ton of failed access:

```
185.103.252.174 - - [28/Apr/2016:15:09:16 -0400] "POST /xmlrpc.php HTTP/1.1" 499 0 "-" "Googlebot/2.1 (+http://www.google.com/bot.html)"
173.246.56.51 - - [28/Apr/2016:15:09:17 -0400] "POST /xmlrpc.php HTTP/1.1" 499 0 "-" "Googlebot/2.1 (+http://www.google.com/bot.html)"
185.103.252.173 - - [28/Apr/2016:15:09:17 -0400] "POST /xmlrpc.php HTTP/1.1" 499 0 "-" "Googlebot/2.1 (+http://www.google.com/bot.html)"
23.226.36.2 - - [28/Apr/2016:15:09:17 -0400] "POST /xmlrpc.php HTTP/1.1" 499 0 "-" "Googlebot/2.1 (+http://www.google.com/bot.html)"
23.226.36.2 - - [28/Apr/2016:15:09:17 -0400] "POST /xmlrpc.php HTTP/1.1" 499 0 "-" "Googlebot/2.1 (+http://www.google.com/bot.html)"
185.103.252.173 - - [28/Apr/2016:15:09:17 -0400] "POST /xmlrpc.php HTTP/1.1" 499 0 "-" "Googlebot/2.1 (+http://www.google.com/bot.html)"
148.251.184.222 - - [28/Apr/2016:15:09:17 -0400] "POST /xmlrpc.php HTTP/1.1" 499 0 "-" "Googlebot/2.1 (+http://www.google.com/bot.html)"
148.251.184.222 - - [28/Apr/2016:15:09:17 -0400] "POST /xmlrpc.php HTTP/1.1" 499 0 "-" "Googlebot/2.1 (+http://www.google.com/bot.html)"
148.251.184.222 - - [28/Apr/2016:15:09:18 -0400] "POST /xmlrpc.php HTTP/1.1" 499 0 "-" "Googlebot/2.1 (+http://www.google.com/bot.html)"
```

My **/etc/fail2ban/filter.d/wordpress-auth.conf**:

```
[Definition]
failregex = <HOST>.*POST.*xmlrpc\.php.* 499
```

In my **/etc/fail2ban/jail.conf**:

```
[wordpress]
enabled  = true
port     = http,https
filter   = wordpress-auth
logpath  = /var/log/nginx/access.log
maxretry = 3
bantime  = 86400
```

I've restarted fail2ban, but I'm not seeing any **[wordpress]** in my **/var/log/fail2ban.log**. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I am being hit with the same IP addresses as you are. Did you trace them down?

Comment: It's not worth the effort, it's presumably a botnet. Just IP block them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right okay it seems it is working, it was just slow to react to the logs.

Comment: On restart, fail2ban re-reads all logs. This can take the better part of an hour sometimes.