# fail2ban filter matches no lines for xmlrpc attack

Tags: ubuntu, regex, fail2ban, brute-force-attacks, filter

I'm trying to jail hosts that brute-force attack a web server, thereby creating (hundreds of) lines in `/var/log/apache2/error.log` of the form

```
[Fri Feb 01 11:17:56.158739 2019] [:error] [pid 15870] [client 40.118.7.71:19920] script '/var/www/html/hello.php' not found or unable to stat
```

**/etc/fail2ban/filter.d/foo.conf:**

```
[INCLUDES]
before = apache-common.conf
[Definition]
failregex = ^%(_apache_error_client)s .* not found or unable to stat
            %(_apache_error_client)s
            [[]client (?P<host>\S*)[]]
```

But `fail2ban-regex /var/log/apache2/error.log foo.conf` reports zero matches for all three of these broader and broader regexes (but no errors or warnings, though.)  So `fail2ban-client status foo` predictably reports no jailings.  I can't broaden the regexes any further, without the error `No 'host' group in '<host>'`.  I've derived these regexes from fail2ban's own `/etc/fail2ban/filter.d/*.conf`'s.

What is a regex that can at least match every line in error.log, as I expected the second and third regex to?  Then I can expand that to more precisely match my particular lines.

(And shouldn't the `apache-noscript` filter be jailing these hosts, anyways?  Its failregex `^%(_apache_error_client)s script '/\S*(\.php|\.asp|\.exe|\.pl)\S*' not found or unable to stat\s*$`) might match my lines.

Ubuntu 14.04, fail2ban v0.8.11.

**Edit:** Related, [I'm trying to catch brute force against /xmlrpc.php with fail2ban](https://serverfault.com/q/773700/270385).  This seems to be called an "xmlrpc attack."

Answer (score 0):

On a whim, from a different distro I derived the regex

```
failregex = \[client <HOST>:\d+\] script '/\S*(\.php|\.asp|\.exe|\.pl)\S*' not found or unable to stat$
```

And indeed a few hours later it had started jailing attackers.  But I'm still surprised that the essential fragment for matching lines in Apache's error.log, `\[client <HOST>:\d+\]`, isn't in `/etc/fail2ban/filter.d/*`.  Version mismatch?